# print if all value are higher

Tags: r, awk

I have a file like:

```
A 50.40,60.80,56.60,67.80,51.20,78.40,63.80,64.2
B 37.40,37.40,38.40,38.80,58.40,58.80,45.00,44.8
.
.
.
```

I want to print those lines that all values in column 2 are more than 50

output:

```
A 50.40,60.80,56.60,67.80,51.20,78.40,63.80,64.2
```

I tried:

```
cat file | tr ',' '\t' | awk '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++){if($i<50) continue; else print $i}}'
```

Comment: have you searched on SO for subsetting matrix or data.frames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you meant that [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag you added to your question.

```
tab <- read.table("file")
splt <- strsplit(as.character(tab[[2]]), ",")
rows <- unlist(lapply(splt, function(a) all(as.numeric(a) > 50)))
tab[rows,]
```

This will read your file as a space-separated table, split the second column into individual values (resulting in a list of character vectors), then compute a logical value for each such row depending on whether or not all values are > 50. These results are combined to a logical vector which is then used to subset your data.

Answer (score 2):

The field separator can be any regular expression, so if you include commas in `FS` your approach works:

```
awk '{ for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) if($i<=50) next } 1' FS='[ \t,]+' infile
```

Output:

```
A 50.40,60.80,56.60,67.80,51.20,78.40,63.80,64.2
```

*Explanation*

The for-loop runs through the comma-separated values in the second column and if any of them is lower than or equal to 50 `next` is executed, i.e. skip to next line. If the first block is passed, the `1` is encountered which evaluates to true and executes the default block: `{ print $0 }`.